# patch is too strict on diff files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, diff, gnu, patch

I need  an automated way to add a line to a configuration file. I used `diff` to create a .diff file that I want to apply with `patch`. However, it can happen that the file that I need to patch is slightly modified elsewhere. E.g. elsewhere in the configuration file some other line has been added.

I assumed that `patch` would actually be smart about this and figure out if the patch could still be applied without conflicts, but I am getting an error whenever I try to apply the patch to a config file that is slightly different from the original file.

Are there any additional flags that I need to pass to `patch` or `diff` to make it less strict? I am generating the .diff file using

```
diff -ruN oldfile.conf newfile.conf > mypatch.diff
```

And then apply the patch using

```
patch myconfig.conf mypatch.diff
```

What I would like is that patch will try to apply the patch fairly liberally, and if it doesn't know how, just return a warning, but not an error. Currently I am seeing these errors:

```
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ diff -ruN default.conf default_new.conf > mypatch.diff
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ patch default2.conf mypatch.diff 
patching file default2.conf
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file default2.conf.rej
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: what error you are actually getting?

Comment: If you only want to add a line, why not write a simple script that adds a line?

Comment: The best tool for this is a proper merge tool, e.g. [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), rather than just patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assumed that patch would actually be smart about this and figure out if the patch could still be applied without conflicts, but I am getting an error whenever I try to apply the patch to a config file that is slightly different from the original file.

Actually, that holds. However, it greatly depends on your definition "slightly different". Basically, changes need to be far from the place modified by the patch.

You can try calling patch with the `-F` argument

> -F num  or  --fuzz=num
>
> Set the maximum fuzz factor.  This option only applies to diffs that have context, and causes patch to ignore up to that many lines of con-
>             text in looking for places to install a hunk.  Note that a larger fuzz factor increases the odds of a faulty patch.  The default fuzz  fac-
>             tor is 2.  A fuzz factor greater than or equal to the number of lines of context in the context diff, ordinarily 3, ignores all context.

But I wouldn't advise it.

If you just want

> an automated way to add a line to a configuration file

did you consider using `perl`, `awk` or `ed` for the job? I don't think `patch` is the right tool for it.

Comment: Is there an easy way to have patch not return an error if it doesn't work?

Comment: @Jeroen: You mean something like `patch ... || true`?

Comment: @Jeroen: Yes, *only* in a shell script.

Comment: Interesting. Is that different from `patch ... 2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: @Jeroen: Yes. `patch ... 2> /dev/null` silences the error output. `patch ... || true` overrides the return value (that is used by the script). You can even combine them: `patch ... 2>/dev/null || true`.